# Django and Google Calendar

Tags: django, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add Gcal integration to my site, and while I can easily display the calendar using OAuth, I can't seem to find a way to add events without making the calendar view public.

Ever person who has access to this website also has editing access to the calendar.  Members want to keep the gcal and not switch to a Django calendar instead.

I'm trying to figure out a way to do the following:

- Keep calendar view private
- Allow members to add events on the group's Django site

Is there a way to do this? I've read that it is not possible to export events which are behind the login page. What package might permit me to do this? Is there a way to integrate a Django calendar package with the Google OAuth? Apologies if this question isn't specific; I'm the only developer working with narrow and changing constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your authorization's scope to read-only should be able to keep your calendar public but not editable. You can find more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

You also might want to check on the [Google Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/sharing#sharing_calendars) for more information regarding the calendars access levels.